# tfs tbl_GitCommitChange not exist in new tfs version

Tags: tfs

We have a query in TFS which uses `tbl_GitCommitChange` with its `IndexedParentPath`, `IndexedChildItem` and `InternalCommitId` with other git tables to find git repo files (fullpath).

In TFS 2017 this table no longer exist. Is there any equivalent table? How can I get git repo file paths in TFS 2017 or 2018?

Thanks

Comment: This is a major reason **you should never query TFS operational stores directly**. The REST APIs exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, table `tbl_GitCommitChange` doesn't exist in TFS 2017 or 2018. You could check the TFS tables change in the following link:

https://healmyscm.wordpress.com/2017/08/03/tfs-databases-schemas-tables/

Instead of querying database, you could use [TFS Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20changes?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to get changes path:

```
GET http://TFS 2017:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=2.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. this might be a good option. We are running microsoft report builder with  the query as part of the datasource. There are quite a few reports which all use tbl_git  tables. So far i have fixed a couple of reports with the schema changes. Ideally, fix through sql directly.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. But the database tables have been changed, and they might change in future versions too. We suggest you use REST API to get information and build report.